# get file address without file name from QFile

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have a `Qfile` with fileName="d://f1/f2/img.jpg". I just want the address of the file ("d://f1/f2). How can I get it without converting to a `QfileInfo`?

Comment: Create a QFileInfo, that's what it's for: `QFileInfo(file).absolutePath()`. Why do you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this link:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#absolutePath

file path:

```
QFileInfo fi("c:/temp/foo"); => fi.absoluteFilePath() => "C:/temp/foo"
```

also file base name:

```
QFileInfo fi("/tmp/archive.tar.gz");
QString base = fi.baseName();  // base = "archive"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 QString folder=file.fileName().section("/",0,-2);
```

the `.section` function separate the content of qstring and label them as below:

```
 _______________________________
| d: | / | /f1 | /f2 | /img.jpg |
 -------------------------------
| 0  | 1 |  2  |  3  |  4       |
 -------------------------------
| -5 |-4 | -3  | -2  | -1       |
 -------------------------------
```

so section("/",0,-2) will return : d://f1/f2

Comment: This syntax is obtuse compared to using `QFileInfo` and is not any more efficient. You seem to think `QFileInfo` does some type of heavy file conversion, but that's not true.

Answer (score 1):

I think the comment by frank-osterfeld is the correct answer:

```
QString fpath (QFileInfo("/home/me/filename.txt").absolutePath());
std::cout << fpath.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

Prints:

```
/home/me
```